# How can I add a dependency to my sbt plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I would like to add a library that I am going to use within the code of my SBT-Plugin.

I did

```
...

sbtPlugin := true

libraryDependencies += "..." %% "..." % "..."

enablePlugins(SbtPlugin)

scriptedLaunchOpts := {
  scriptedLaunchOpts.value ++
    Seq("-Xmx1024M", "-Dplugin.version=" + version.value)
}

scriptedBufferLog := false

...
```

in `build.sbt` located in the root of my plugin project.

```
▶ tree -L 1
.
├── README.md
├── build.sbt <- this one
├── project
└── src
```

---

But when I run the test, following: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing-sbt-plugins.html .

I run

```
sbt 'set isSnapshot := true' scripted
```

And I am getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

with some class coming from the library I added.

---

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Can you add the details for the scripted test?

Comment: can you try adding `libraryDependencies += "..." %% "..." % "..."` to the `project/plugins.sbt` file instead of your `build.sbt` file?

Comment: @laughedelic I just followed the simple test from https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing-sbt-plugins.html nothing fancy.

Comment: @terminally-chill but then it wont be available inside the src folder to use, correct ? It will only be used to help build the project itself.

Comment: Yes. A plugin is used for the project build, it doesn't add its dependencies to the code in the project. If you want to do that, it's also possible, but it's a different thing.